# Explicit constructor and initialization with std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class P { 
    public:
explicit P( int a, int b, int c) {  
    std::cout<<"calling explicit constructor"<<"\n";
    } 

};


int main() {

P z {77,5,42}; // OK

P w = {77,5,42}; // ERROR due to explicit (no implicit type conversion allowed)

}
```

I think  `{77,5,42}` has the implicit type of `std::initialization_list<int>`. If that is the case what is not causing the failure of construction of variable `z`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think `{77,5,42}` has the implicit type of `std::initialization_list<int>`

`{77,5,42}` by itself has no type. If you write `auto x = {77, 5, 42}` then `x` is of type `initializer_list`. Your example type `P` has an explicit constructor. Effectively, this means you have to write:

```
P w = P{77, 5, 42}
```

Or better:

```
auto w = P{77, 5, 42}
```

> If that is the case what is not causing the failure of construction of variable `z`?

The construction does not fail because you *are* initializing it explicitly: `P x{a, b, c}` does not perform an implicit conversion of any kind, but simply uses the uniform initialization syntax to invoke the (explicit) constructor of `P`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is trying to do implicit conversion by finding a constructor that can match the

```
= {77,5,42};
```

part.

However, the constructor it finds, is marked explicit so it can't be used for implicit conversion. Consequently you'll get an error.

This may be of interest: [What does the explicit keyword mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)